# Kendo - Linear Guage: Change Scale/Steps Color

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have the following Kendo UI LinearGuage:

```
@(Html.Kendo().LinearGauge()
  .Name("lGuage")
  .Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(28).Color("orange"))

  .Scale(scale => scale
    .MajorUnit(20)
    .MinorUnit(2)
    .Min(0)
    .Max(100)              
    .Labels(labels => labels
     .Color("#fff")
     )
    .Ranges(ranges =>
     {
         ranges.Add().From(0).To(20).Color("#2798df");
         ranges.Add().From(30).To(45).Color("#ffc700");
         ranges.Add().From(45).To(60).Color("#c20000");
     }
   )
 )
)
```

It produces the following:

[image]

How can I update the scale/steps color(**currently not shown because they are the same color as the background*) . I have not been able to find much on this. I'm trying to avoid overriding CSS approach if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the Scale.MajorTicks.Color and the Scale.Line.Color.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

**Updated Code:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().LinearGauge()
                  .Name("lGuage")
                  .Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(28).Color("black"))
                  .Scale(scale => scale
                      .MajorUnit(20)
                      .MinorUnit(2)
                      .Min(0)
                      .Max(100)
                      .Line(line=>line
                          .Color("#fff")
                      )
                        .MajorTicks(mticks => mticks
                        .Color("#fff")
                    )
                      .Labels(labels => labels
                          .Color("#fff"))
                      .Ranges(ranges =>
                      {
                          ranges.Add().From(0).To(20).Color("#2798df");
                          ranges.Add().From(30).To(45).Color("#ffc700");
                          ranges.Add().From(45).To(60).Color("#c20000");
                      }
                      )
                  )
             )
```